Maui.net iOS 18 Shell showing Tite when Shell.TitleView is defined
I have replaced the Shell.Title with a Shell.TitleView in my AppShell.xaml.   All good except for iOS 18.
 <ShellContent
 Title="HIDE ME"
 ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AttendPage}"
 Route="AttendPage" />

And the Shell.TitleView
 <Shell.TitleView>
 <HorizontalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill">

     <ImageButton
         x:Name="TButton"
         Source="back.png"
         Aspect="Center"
         Clicked="TButton_Clicked" />

     <Label 
         x:Name="myTitleView"
         Text=""
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
         BackgroundColor="White"
         TextColor="Black"
         FontAttributes="Bold"
         FontSize="Medium">  
     </Label>
 </HorizontalStackLayout>

</Shell.TitleView>
This is the same code running on 17.5 and 18 simulators.  Does the same thing on iOS devices.


Probably worth raising on https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions

So, I found a workaround for this.
Please see: GitHub issue #26114  for the solution.
